# Python memory array shared among multiple threads (think memcached in process space)

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, memcached

So I have a program that is multi threaded, in a nutshell it downloads web pages, processes them and stores the results. The rules and whatnot it uses to process the web pages are stored within a database. Initially the database was absolutely hammered (1-50 requests to the database were needed to process each web page). Step 1 was caching this information in memcached (and if there are no rules for a domain it simply returns an empty string ""), a huge improvement vs. hammering the database 1-50 times for each processed item. But I am still hammering memcached which is adding network latency (1-50 round trips for each processed item, it adds up quickly, even on local Ethernet).

So I'd like to cache the results within an array in the process space, basically replicating memcached in memory. Data-wise it's not too bad, I'm going to use a Python set to basically replicate the key:value store (easy enough).

But here's the thing: typically a bunch of threads will hit the same site and need the same rule set, so I'd like to prevent the thundering herd problem (i.e. 10 threads all trying to get the rules for example.com, which if not in the local cache, and not in the memcached will result in the database getting hit, not terribly hard, but somewhat).

1. Setup a thread ("update_thread") to update the in memory array, have a work queue, if a thread can't get rules for a domain from the local cache it writes the domain to the work queue and sleep for part of a second then tries again, sleeping and trying again until the local memory cache has either an empty string "" or a set of rules to use. The thread "update_thread" reads the work queue and gets the rules from memcached or if not there from the database and writes them to memcached and the local cache (and if there are no rules propagates an empty string "" in the value). The downsides of this are adding a thread; more GIL contention, slight delays (we have to wait for the update_thread to run since we're at the mercy of the GIL). Plus the added complexity of another thread and a work queue. Only the "update_thread" can write to the in memory cache array so there is no need for locking/etc.
2. We use a lock to control write access to the cache array in memory. If a thread can't find a rule set it attempts to get the rule set from memcached, if not in there it hits the database, once it finds the rules it locks the memory array and writes the rules (or an empty string "" for the value) to the memory cache. Downside: we may still have the thundering herd problem, but this could be offset by writing a special value such as "getting the rules so just wait a second" for a domain which would cause the other threads to wait for example.

Can anyone else think of any other solutions, or comment on the two solutions I have come up with? I suspect I will go with number 2 since locking + the "getting the rules so just wait a second" seems simpler than adding a thread and a work queue. Or am I missing some blindingly obvious and simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, the problem is that multiple threads tend to retrieve the same data from memcached simultaneously. You'd like to coordinate the threads so that one thread retrieves the data, while others wait, and share the data after it has arrived.

Make a wrapper class for the objects you want to cache. Place an empty wrapper in the cache before starting to retrieve a value over the network. If another thread looks for the same data, it will block until the value arrives.

Here's the wrapper object:

```
class PendingValue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._event = threading.Event()

    def get(self):
        self._event.wait()
        return self._value

    def set(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self._event.set()
```

and here's the cache:

```
class Cache(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = {}
        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self._lock.acquire()
        try:
            pv = self._dict[key]
            self._lock.release()
            return pv.get()
        except KeyError: #key not in cache
            pv = PendingValue()
            self._dict[key] = pv
            self._lock.release()
            value = retrieve_value_from_external_source()
            pv.set(value)
            return value
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty big jump to go from a separate, controlled process space to shared memory and some kind of mutex.

If your problem is latency introduced by fifty round trips to process something, why don't you use multiget and always just do one?

Comment: Essentially processing rules are broken up by domain. So a single web page can easily hit many domains (and thus rulesets), the latency of this is... annoying and unnecessary. Plus I have threads getting many web pages so even with multiget there's going to be a good chunk of network traffic/etc. Thus the in memory cache to avoid all this. Plus the rulesets are relatively long lived so no need to be constantly fetching them.

Comment: You can ask for more than one thing at a time with memcached.  50 rulesets shouldn't take you more than one network round trip.  Putting a second tier of caching on your memcached cached data will possibly benefit you, but it'll be a trade-off.

Comment: Right but that means for each page I parse I'm hitting memcached regardless for data I probably just requested for the last page I processed (so keeping it in memory would prevent that). It adds up. 10,000 pages times 100ms added latency, and so on.

Comment: If you have 100ms latency, you're doing something horribly wrong.  memcached should be at the very least an order of magnitude faster than anything you're fetching from the internet.  You can still have a secondary cache in the app if you're asking for the same data on subsequent requests, but I'd recommend working on using what you've got more effectively before just changing everything.